# Generating a random walk with defined step size

Tags: random

By the following I'm trying to generate a list of random coordinates (ex. 4) each within unit distance from previous one, starting from origin. What am I doing wrong?

```
o = {0, 0, 0};

RP = Module[{},
  RN = RandomReal[1000, 3];
  RV1 = RN/(2*RootMeanSquare[RN]);
 o = RV1 + o;
 RV2 = {};
 RV2 = Append[RV2, o]
 ]

In[231]:= Do[RP, {i, 1, 4}]
RV2
```

Comment: Welcome to MMA.SE! Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) and try to format your code (see [Markdown help](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) ).

Comment: Your code does contain quite a few problematic/ inconsistent bits, e.g. the `Module` is essentially useless and you should be using `:=` instead of `=`, you reset `RV` each time and `Do` does not work like you might be assuming. Please read up on the help tutorials and e.g. this thread [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/131)

Comment: These are essentially duplicates and contain good solutions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5470/speeding-up-random-walk-for-many-particles and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/3d-random-walk-with-periodic-boundary-conditions.

Comment: @whuber although the question "What am I doing wrong" is not properly answered yet

Comment: @Yves I hear you. On the other hand, questions of the form "here's my code, please find my mistake" are not acceptable anywhere on SE.  Evidently we are a kind and tolerant community.  It appears to me that the answers emerging here do not augment the [existing answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/3d-random-walk-with-periodic-boundary-conditions) in any material way.

Comment: @whuber agreed. I still think it might be useful in the sense of a basic, no-frill random walk question if rephrased. The other questions are much more elaborate...

Answer (score 6):

Since the origin is defined with $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates, I guess that the random list should be in 3D. Some good hints can be found on this [page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13038/685).

To implement the path in 3D space with steps equal to unit vectors we can take this approach:

```
rand3Ddir = #*Normalize@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 3] &;
origin = {0, 0, 0};
steps = Prepend[Table[rand3Ddir[1], {100}], origin];
path = Accumulate[steps];
Graphics3D[{Line[path], PointSize[Large], Red, Point[path]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
n=1000;
start={{0.,0.,0.}}
distances=Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1,1}, {n, 3}];
coordinates=Accumulate[Join[start,distances]];
```

Comment: Your path is pointing in the (1,1,1) direction.

Comment: `RandomReal[{-1,1}, {n, 3}]` or similar?

Comment: Indeed! Corrected the post.

Comment: Althogh... the OP also used a positive range, perhaps not wholly intentionally ;-)

Comment: Note the difference between using `Normalize @ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]` and `Normalize@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 3]` in this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13040/685).

Comment: @VLC for the novice user `NormalDistribution` may be a bit advanced / frightening.

Comment: @YvesKlett You're right, but since I don't know what the application of this 3D random walk will be, I just wanted to note that there are some subtle differences between the two approaches.

Comment: Actually there's quite an important difference.  `RandomReal[{-1,1}, {n, 3}]` gives vectors uniformly distributed in a cube. The *direction* of the vectors is not uniformly distributed on a sphere.  But it's true that it [won't change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) the random walk much.

Comment: @Yves, as VLC notes, you end up with a somewhat *biased* random walk if you use the `RandomReal[]` construction.

Comment: @JuanJoder, good point. You could go for spherical coordinates, but then the solution is not so concise.

Answer (score 2):

```
 rndmwlk = NestList[# +  RandomReal[1] Normalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}]] &,
  {0., 0.,  0.}, 100];

 Graphics3D[{Tube@rndmwlk, PointSize[.04], Black, Sphere[rndmwlk[[1]], .15],
  {Hue[RandomReal[]], Sphere[#, .1]} & /@ rndmwlk[[2 ;;]]}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: ahh... "within" vs. "with" unit distance...

Comment: @Yves, right :)